# Trouble restoring cached data in sessionStorage with Next.js and React

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am new to Next.js, but I have build many React apps.

I am trying to restore crucial user data, every time the user refreshes the page.

I am used to restoring user data in sessionStorage in react like so :

App.tsx

```
    // Load cache
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        const selectionCache = sessionStorage.getItem('selection');
        if (selectionCache) {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_SELECTION,
                payload: JSON.parse(selectionCache)
            });
        }

        const modelCache = sessionStorage.getItem('model');
        if (modelCache) {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_MODEL,
                payload: JSON.parse(modelCache)
            });
        }
    }, [dispatch, config.product, selection.items]);
```

This will load the sessionStorage data, in our context api global store, every time the user refreshes the page.

However, this is not working now that im running with Next.js. I have put this code in _app.tsx, does it only run on the server? Where else could i put this code, to have a global state refresh? And can i get the session cache to work in other ways?